# Pass ItemClicked in MvxRecyclerView object to new View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm newbie in Xamarin.

I have MvxRecyclerView to show list of Cars. Clicking in a car let user to display full specification of chosen car. I have problem with displaying full specification of chosen car in new activity (and at the same time pass object between viewmodels)

My MvxRecyclerView .xml looks like:

```
    <mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_car"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Cars; ItemClick NavigateCommand"
        />
```

And my CarsViewModel with "empty" navigation to CarItemViewModel:

```
public class CarsViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public CarsViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            Cars = new MvxObservableCollection<Car>();
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            NavigateCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(() => _navigationService.Navigate<CarItemViewModel>());
        }

        private MvxObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
        public MvxObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get => _cars;
            set
            {
                _cars = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Cars);
            }
        }

        public override async Task Initialize()
        {
            await base.Initialize();
            CarService carService = new CarService();
            await Task.Run(async () =>
             {
                 Cars = await carService.GetCars();
             });
        }

        private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
        public IMvxAsyncCommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }
```

Do you know how is it possible to move data of chosen mvxrecyclerview item to new view using MVVMCross? Unfortunately, I don't understand what MVVMCross' documentation says about this (it looks so poor in my opinion).

I would appreciate for any help.

EDIT 1:
I've changed a bit description of my problem for more transparent.

Comment: Can this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698059/xamarin-forms-passing-data-between-pages-views

Comment: I know how to do that using "raw'" c#, but I have to do it using mvvmcross and that's the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the document is clear about passing parameter, [here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation):

When you navigation, you should pass a `MyObject` of `CarItemViewModel`:

```
   await _navigationService.Navigate<CarItemViewModel, MyObject>(new MyObject());
```

And then you can get the `MyObject` in the `CarItemViewModel` and use it:

```
public class CarItemViewModel: MvxViewModel<MyObject>
{
    private MyObject _myObject;

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        // first callback. Initialize parameter-agnostic stuff here
    }

    public override void Prepare(MyObject parameter)
    {
        // receive and store the parameter here
        _myObject = parameter;
    }
    
    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();

        // do the heavy work here
    }
}
```